# psexec -d option breaks vbscripts

Tags: vbscript, psexec

For some reason when I use PSEXEC with the -d option my script will start to execute and then fail on a remote machine. If I dont use -d option the script will execute properly on the remote machine. Also if I launch the script manually on the remote machine it will execute properly.

psexec is being launch from one vbscript and that instance of psexec launch another vbscript on the remote machine. This is my launch string:

```
returnError = runCommandLine(psexecPath & " \\" & machine & " -d -u " & username & " -p " & password & " cscript \\servername\DHCPEnabler$\DHCPEnabler.vbs" & " /machineip:" & machine)
```

When using the -d option the script DHCPEnabler.vbs does get executed on the remote machine but fails half way through running

Here is my DHCPEnabler.vbs script http://www.pastebin.ca/2640148
The place that seems to fail is right around

```
errdns = myshell.run("netsh interface ip set dns " & chr(34) & wmiItem.NetConnectionID & chr(34) & " dhcp" , 0, true)
errwins = myshell.run("netsh interface ip set wins " & chr(34) & wmiItem.NetConnectionID & chr(34) & " dhcp" , 0, true)
errdhcp = myshell.run("netsh interface ip set address " & chr(34) & wmiItem.NetConnectionID & chr(34) & " dhcp" , 0, true)
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding %COMSPEC% /C to the beginning of your command line. Like this:

```
returnError = runCommandLine(psexecPath & " \\" & machine & " -d -u " &_
              username & " -p " & password &_
              " %COMSPEC% /C cscript \\servername\DHCPEnabler$\DHCPEnabler.vbs" &_
              " /machineip:" & machine)
```